# Printing multiple sheets with Mail Merge (Excel/Word)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I need to create letters with MS Word. On each letter we need a code which is placed on the letter using Mail Merge. Some letters need to be printed more often than others. I need to find a way to have some letters created more often than others without duplicating the amount of rows in Excel. We have a column in the list with the number of times the letter needs to be printed, but I don't know how to use this data in the mail merge.

Columns:

```
A: Amount (amount of times the letter needs to be printed)
B: Code 1
C: Code 2
```

An example of the documents [can be found here](https://topcats.nl/documents/mailmerge-example.zip).

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to loop a unique record by the number of iterations specified in the helper column.

With the standard word/excel setup it is not possible.

Word Mail merge has `if..then..else` rule, but the `then/else` field is limited to text only. The `{}` Field names are not recognized there. Also, the `if` statement is compared against a constant, not a variable value from helper column.

The easiest way is to repeat the row in excel list as many times as required. Otherwise somebody with VBA skills may shed some light if this looping is possible with VBA help.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.. But thanks for the reply! I will look into another solution  than Word/Excel :)

Answer (score 0):

After preparing the sheet in Excel and linking it with word mail merge (start mail merge) use edit recipient and use Filter choose Amount equal to write the number of times, it will show only the records with the corresponding Amount and you can send it to print

Comment: OP is not asking to print the selective records (& hence you suggesting to filter). He is asking how to print `Code 1` xyz times `Amount`

Answer (score 0):

"without duplicating the rows in Excel"

One way to do that, as long as you have a reasonably small maximum possible repetition count, is by doing a two-step merge. Say "Amount" can be 1, 2, or 3.

In step one you have a directory mail merge main document something like this:

```
{ IF { MERGESEQ } = 1 "Code1,Code2" }
{ IF { MERGEFIELD Amount } > 0 "{ MERGEFIELD Code1 },{ MERGEFIELD Code2 }" }
{ IF { MERGEFIELD Amount } > 1 "{ MERGEFIELD Code1 },{ MERGEFIELD Code2 }" }
{ IF { MERGEFIELD Amount } > 2 "{ MERGEFIELD Code1 },{ MERGEFIELD Code2 }" }
```

Merge that to an output document and you should have a new .docx with the correct number of copies of the data you need. Use that as your data source for step 2.

(If your data is actually more complicated than you have suggested, then you may need to deal with the possibility that your data fields contain commas).

There is one other possible "two-step" approach that *may* be workable if you are using Windows Word, depending on how many rows your Excel sheet contains and how large "Amount" can be.